# Interactive Treemap d3tree in RStudio - no legend when savewidget() is used

Tags: r, treemap, htmlwidgets, d3tree

need some help and would be grateful for any advice. I want to create an interactive treemap in R. So far, so good, so bad. I managed that and was able to create an HTML widget, but when I open it, the legend isn't there anymore. In the original plot it is still there, but not as a saved file. I would be grateful for tips! this is my code:

```
library(tidyverse) library(readr) library(lubridate) library(ggthemes) library(treemap) library(d3treeR) library(readxl) library(htmlwidgets) df <- read_excel("df.xlsx")

Tidydata <- df %>% group_by(Level1, Level2, Level3) %>% summarise(Count = n())

tree <- treemap(Tidydata, index=c("Level1", "Level2", "Level3") ,vSize="Count" ,vColor="Count", type="value", border.col=c("black","white"), palette = "Greens", title="Treemap",
fontsize.title=16, fontsize.labels = 7, title.legend = "Counts" )

int <- d3tree(tree,width = "200%", height ="600px", rootname = "Level1")

saveWidget(int, file="TreePlot.html", selfcontained = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found out how to resolve the Problem with the missing legend and the overlapping issues.

If you are struggeling with the same issue, please use

```
int <- **d3tree2**(tree,width = "200%", height ="600px", rootname = "Level1")
```

instead of

```
int <- d3tree(tree,width = "200%", height ="600px", rootname = "Level1")

and you can create very nice interactive treemaps.
```